# How to get Smooth Scrolling with Magic Mouse?

Tags: touchpad, scrolling, magic-mouse

Smooth Scrolling with the laptop's touchpad works in almost every app (nautilus, software center, gedit..) but not with Apple's Magic Mouse. This mouse has touch surface and is just like a touchpad, but it acts like a scroll wheel when scrollign.

Also, notice that in firefox, with smooth scrolling enabled, magic mouse works exactly like the laptop's touchpad. Its the same, I dont notice any difference.

Is it possible to make it work also in all the other apps like in firefox?

Comment: check this ->http://askubuntu.com/questions/744416/how-to-get-smooth-scrolling-movement-with-magic-mouse.